# Access remote SFTP server via Wordpress login?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, uploads, plugin-recommendation, server

I currently have an active Wordpress site and a running SFTP server that I manage locally. My Wordpress site is also hosted locally using LAMP. My question is if anyone knows of a way to integrate the SFTP server into my Wordpress site so that users can log in and access files stored on the SFTP server? I know I could simply upload all my files to the Wordpress site but I’d have to do a massive amount of work if I went that route. I’d like my clients to be able to access the SFTP server without having to download client software or use a special browser.

Comment: That completely depends on the SFTP server you're using, and you can hook into its authentication or delegate authentication to WordPress.

Comment: I’m using Bitvise. Any idea where to start? Any specific plugins?

Comment: It's probably a Bitvise question really then: you'd need to find out from them how they can integrate with external authentication, and then you can work out what WordPress plugins or changes you need to set up what Bitvise can authenticate with.